# Treatment and Control group, the sample size

Tags: sample, case-control-study

I am doing the evaluation for a program with 200 members (they enrolled in the program at different times in the past year and the program doesn't end). Only 78 completed the pre test survey. Now I have to look for a control group and resources are scant... What is the ideal number of a sample size for the control group? What is the optimal number? 
I also know it is a big limitation that treatment and control group didn't take the pre test at the same time, how big is that limitation?
Thanks!
M.

Comment: It is rather hard to say in the abstract. What kind of data do you have? Eg, do you think of the response as continuous? How big of a difference between the treatment & control groups do you want to be able to detect?

Comment: Yes, my main health outcomes are BMI, blood pressure, and glucose level.

Answer (score 1):

In epidemiological research an optimal ratio is of 4 controls to 1 case (assuming it's an unmatched design). After that, power increases but at a decreasing rate as the ratio of controls/cases increases.

[image]

from Woodward, M. Epidemiology Study Design and Analysis. Boca Raton: Chapman and Hall:, 1999, p.265

Comment: Thanks Marijana. Although this is not an epidemiological research. This is a health program, focused on wellness and prevention...

Comment: hi Mariana, I think the same methodological issues apply to public health intervention. What effect size do you wish to achieve with your program? e.g. odds ratio of 1.5, or 2? What is the prevalence of the risk factors. With this information, you can use standard online sample size calculators, like http://sampsize.sourceforge.net/iface/s3.html#ccp